# How much difference can 2D acceleration in VirtualBox bring?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to know how much difference can 2D acceleration in VirtualBox bring ? I only run graphical interface on Windows VMs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Virtual Box has a still experimental feature to use 2D video acceleration of your host graphic card in a Windows (only!) guest.

> Windows VM uses 2D video overlays to play a movie clip, then VirtualBox will attempt to use your host's video acceleration hardware instead of performing overlay stretching and color conversion in software<sup>[Virtual Box Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-2d)</sup>

This means that you'd expect a performance benefit for video applications in a virtual Windows only. This however is not the typical use case for a virtual machine, as we do have quite mature video playback software natively supported from Ubuntu.

Comment: That's good, I would never play a video in VM

Answer (score 2):

I am using 2DBench to have some numbers about 2D performance:
http://www.tomshardware.de/download/Tom2D,1601-26150.html
I have run the test three times:

1. PAE/NX + VT/x + Nested Paging **+ 2D acceleration**:

   ```
   BENCHMARK: DIRECT DRAWING TO VISIBLE DEVICE

   Text: 9677 chars/sec  
   Line: 28425 lines/sec  
   Polygon: 5402 polygons/sec  
   Rectangle: 3201 rects/sec  
   Arc/Ellipse: 10900 ellipses/sec  
   Blitting: 4993 operations/sec  
   Stretching: 257 operations/sec  
   Splines/Bézier: 11639 splines/sec  
   Score: 836
   ```
2. PAE/NX + VT/x + Nested Paging **without 2D acceleration**

   ```
   BENCHMARK: DIRECT DRAWING TO VISIBLE DEVICE

   Text: 8092 chars/sec
   Line: 18521 lines/sec
   Polygon: 7725 polygons/sec
   Rectangle: 2911 rects/sec
   Arc/Ellipse: 12267 ellipses/sec
   Blitting: 5599 operations/sec
   Stretching: 225 operations/sec
   Splines/Bézier: 11910 splines/sec
   Score: 826
   ```

What I have noticed is that my host cpu usage was smaller. So the vm was using my host gpu for some action to lower the cpu usage.

So basically it "brings" you more host performance because not every single 2D action is emulated through the CPU.